# Why do I see high CPU usage for one process but the overall CPU idle percentage is high?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage

This is a 8 core machine.
The %Cpu(s)->id is 99.4 but one java process already occupies 82.7% cpu usage.

The "top" output is as below:

```
top - 09:04:09 up 17:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 142 total,   1 running,  74 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
KiB Mem : 62876640 total,  9865752 free, 51971500 used,  1039388 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 10121552 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4859 root      20   0   50.1g  49.4g 144356 S  82.7 82.4  20:28.62 java
 3847 root      20   0    6452    792    716 S   0.3  0.0   0:09.50 rngd
    1 root      20   0   43724   5680   4196 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.30 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
```

Comment: Try htop instead, it shows at the top each core usage.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

the answer:

we have cpu = 8 cores

from top we have:
process cpu_usage = 82.7%
idle = 99.4 % id

look ! lets calculate

8 cores  at full usage give = 800%,

so cpu usage % = > [82.7/800] * 100% = 10.3 % (calculated)

cpu idle % = 100-10.3 = 89.7 % (calculated)

well 89.7% kind of slightly different from 99.4% but will 
give you a flavour

i suppose your main confusion is about 82.7%.

82.7%  does not mean 82.7% usage of all the cpu. it would be so if your cpu had 1 core. for multicore cpus 100% usage means that kind of only one core is 100% busy
not all the cpu.

Answer (score -1):

Hello it's depending on your usage, running service or apps (eclipse, android studio, JBoss Server, etc...) check them.

Answer (score -1):

Normally the CPU tries to distribute the functions/process between its cores in order to fulfill the multi-tasking. So, the specific process can fetch up the big part of one the cores, however the other cores and the CPU are not handling a huge load.

BR